# Integration of an exponential function

Tags: calculus

Integrate the following function : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(a^2x^2 + \frac{b^2}{x^2})} dx$$

Using Mathematica, I found that the answer to this Integral was:

$$\frac{\sqrt\pi}a e^{-2ab}$$

Can someone please tell me how we got this answer?

Comment: Have you heard of the erf/erfi function?

Comment: @John: that's not needed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, oh I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ I = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-a^2 x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}\right)\,dx = \frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-x^2-\frac{(ab)^2}{x^2}\right)\,dx$$
By setting $\left(x-\frac{ab}{x}\right)=u\tag{1}$ we have:
$$ I = \frac{e^{-2ab}}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{u}{\sqrt{4ab+u^2}}\right)e^{-u^2}\,du \tag{2}$$
and since the integral of an odd integrable function over a symmetric domain with respect to the origin is just zero,
$$ I = \frac{e^{-2ab}}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}\,du = \frac{e^{-2ab}}{a}\sqrt{\pi} \tag{3}$$ as wanted.

Comment: In the first step how did you take out (1/a) from the integral?

Comment: @KaustavSen: it is just the obvious substitution, $x=\frac{z}{a}$, leading to $dx=\frac{1}{a}\,dz$.